# Evaluating template literals dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have template literal like so:

```
const templateLiteral = `string text ${expression} string text`
```

I want to dynamically evaluate the template literal into a finished string.

```
function toFoo(templateLiteral){
   //returns "string text Foo string text"
   return templateLiteral.evaluate('Foo');  
}

function toBar(templateLiteral){
  //returns "string text Bar string text"
   return templateLiteral.evaluate('Bar');  
}

function toBaz(templateLiteral){
   //returns "string text Baz string text"
   return templateLiteral.evaluate('Baz');  
}
```

is there a way to do something like this with template literals, or am I just being dumb? (template.evaluate() is a made up function, but I am looking for that kind of functionality with JS!).

Comment: Sort of sounds like a general replace function no?

Comment: But...wouldn't a template literal (like all literals) be evaluated at the point where it appears, creating a string that doesn't know it came from a literal?

Comment: probably not if it's wrapped in a function :)

Comment: You can find valuable information about template literals -https://indepth.dev/posts/1362/getting-started-with-modern-javascript-template-literals

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to do this is quite obvious, simply reverse the situation given by the question. *You just need to wrap the template literals in a function*, and then you will delay evaluation until you pass in the desired params. It's that simple.

```
function evaluteTemplateLiteral(bar){
  return `foo ${bar} baz`;
}
```

now if you wanted to get fancier, you could create this:

```
function evaluateGeneric(vals, fn){
   return fn.apply(null, vals);
}
```

and you would use the above like so:

```
evaluateGeneric(['brown','fox','cholo'], function(){
    return `the quick ${arguments[0]} fox ${arguments[1]}`;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) could help in this scenario:

```
function toFoo(strings, ...values) {
    console.log(strings[0]); // string text
    console.log(strings[1]); // string text
    console.log(values[0]);  // <your-passed-expression>

    // TODO: Do your manipulation
}

const val = toFoo`string text ${expression} string text`;
```

`strings` contains the "normal" tokens of the line and `values` are the "variable" parts. Please note that you have to concatenate the string manually.

Comment: In your example `strings` will be `["string text ", " string text"]`, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

i would just call eval, you are evaluating code anyway when using template strings

Comment: Eval is fun, but it could do something bad in some cases, since it's so generic

Answer (score 0):

Reusable and simplified templating function with dynamic values.

```js
const contentTemplate = (template, dynamicValues, callback, selector) => {
  const regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
  const result = template.replace(regex, (match, captureKey) => { 
    return dynamicValues[captureKey] || '';
  })
  callback && callback(result, selector)
  return result
}

const content = 'Hello, My is {{name}}, age is {{age}} and Im from {{city}}';
const dynamicValues = {
  name: 'Amoos',
  age: 28,
  city: 'Paris'
}

const addContentFunction = ( tranformedContent, selector ) => {
  const app = document.querySelector(selector)
  app.innerHTML = tranformedContent ? tranformedContent : 'No content!'
}

contentTemplate(content, dynamicValues, addContentFunction, '#myId')
contentTemplate(content, {name: 'Rifat', age: 24, city: 'Berlin' }, addContentFunction, '.myClass')
```

```html
<div id="myId"></div>
<hr />
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: my answer is more idiomatic, I think, and with typescript you could do type-checking, etc